# Array for loops

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

I wanted the output to be 1, 4, 9, 16, 25.... etc.

Here's my code:

```
public class ArrayDemo{
    public static main(String[]args){
       int [] value = new int[20];
       int copy = value[1];

        for(int i = 0; i <values.length; i+=3)
        {
             i = i + 1;
             System.out.println(i);
        }
```

I know I'm doing something wrong.. just can't seem to figure out what. It just prints out 1, 4, 7, .. etc. -___- any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Your array is empty.

Comment: You have to change the `i+=3` to `i+=j`, start `j` as 3 and increase it by 2 at every iteration.

Comment: And your for loop has nothing to do with your value array. Do you want to print square numbers sequentially?

Comment: 1,4,9,15,25,... = 1^2,2^2,3^2,4^2,5^2,...

Comment: You just write a code to print square of natural numbers. That's it

Answer (score 2):

to print out squares of numbers try

```
 for (int x = 1; x <= 5; x++) {
     System.out.println (x*x);
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

Change this:

```
for (int i=0; i<value.length; i+=3)
{
     i = i + 1;
     System.out.println(i);
}
```

To This:

```
for (int i=1,j=3; i<value.length; i+=j,j+=2)
{
     System.out.println(i);
}
```

Of course, you can run a standard loop and print `i*i`, but I suppose you wanted to do it differently.

By the way, you may as well get rid of that `value` array, and use 20 instead of `value.length`.

Comment: not sure what you are trying to acheive here.

Comment: @ScaryWombat: Trying to take OP's code and make it work in his/her "terms" (obviously, they are trying to achieve something other thna printing `i*i`).

Comment: Ah I don't know about that, it taught me something.

Comment: @ScaryWombat I think it's a roundabout way to print the sequence of squares: (n + 1)^2 = n^2 + 2n + 1.  So j in this case is the sequence 2n + 1.

Comment: @barakmanos I don't even see the point of commenting because I think this is almost a spoof answer, but really it should be `i < values.length*values.length` since `i` now represents the square of the "nth" value (and presumable they want the `value.length` first squares).

Comment: @Jared: I'm not sure what's the point in using that `values` array to begin with.

Comment: @barakmanos agreed on that point!

Comment: I should correct my flippant comment about this method, because it's _not_ a "roundabout way" to print the sequence of squares--it's actually a very efficient way.  It would technically be faster than computing `i*i` each time since integer addition is _much faster_ than integer multiplication.

Answer (score 1):

```
for ( int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    System.out.println(i*i);
}
```

And that's all

Answer (score 1):

First of all, it is not clean code, the array "value" and the variable "copy" don't have any real purpose.
Secondly, it will not even compile, as you have array named "value" and the "for" loop refers to "values".
Thirdly, you want to print squares of integers from 1 to 20. Better way to do it would be:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 20; i++)
    System.out.println (i * i);
```

Comment: So this is actually javascript, yes?  Didn't know you could do that here, that's cool!